# Using Viscosity VPN for Mac OS X, How Do I Set DNS Server Dynamically When Connected?

Tags: vpn, mac-osx

I am using Viscosity VPN for Mac OS X 10.5.

I would like to configure the networking on our users' mac laptops to use the company's DNS server (so it will resolve the names of internal nodes) when the VPN is connected, and *not* use company's DNS server when VPN is *not* connected.

Anyone in SF land know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, one programs the DNS servers into the OpenVPN configuration one loads into Viscosity.

As gleaned from this post about how Viscosity's "Use Alternate DNS" post [here](http://www.viscosityvpn.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19)